# Why and how does a foreach-loop on BlockingCollection run infinite?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, foreach, blockingcollection

I'm working on a simple file logger, had problems with thread-safety and was looking at how others are doing it.
I came across the approach to use a BlockingCollection as a queue and a foreach-loop to process that queue:

```cs
var queue = new BlockingCollection<string>(1024);
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                                        foreach (var message in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
                                            WriteMessageToFile(message);
                                        }
                                    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

```vb
Dim queue = New BlockingCollection(Of String)(1024)
Dim t = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                  For Each message In queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()
                                      WriteMessageToFile(message)
                                  Next
                              End Sub, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
```

This For Each loop does actually run infinite. It processes data that I add to `queue`, until I call `.CompleteAdding` on the BlockingCollection.

I wonder why that works like that and how and if this is a good approach.
What does the thread do while the collection is empty, does it check every tick? Is that not ressource-heavy?

Comment: Without the producer explicitly indicating there will be no more data, how would you expect the consuming enumerable to tell the difference between "the collection is currently empty but that could change" (and, therefore, continue the enumeration) and "the collection is currently empty and that will never change" (and, therefore, abandon the enumeration)?  They're (at least) two separate threads/tasks, so one needs to communicate that to the other _somehow_.

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. No, it doesn’t check every tick; it does block a thread, but the O/S won’t schedule that thread for execution when the collection is empty.

Comment: @BACON What? Isn't that my question? How does it know? foreach normally does nothing on an empty collection, why does it not here?

Comment: @JohnWu Wow, that's nifty. How does the O/S know that the collection is empty? Is that logic implemented in the BlockingCollection or does it just work like that?

Comment: The way it knows is, as you say, "call `.CompleteAdding`" so, no, your question seems to be "I wonder why that works like that". I'm saying if there weren't the requirement to call `CompleteAdding()` how else would it determine that there is truly no more data? What if you start the producer and consumer tasks at the same time and the consumers happen to get to the collection first before it contains data, or data is produced slower than it's consumed? If they permanently gave up enumerating the collection because it happened to be empty at that moment, that wouldn't be very useful, would it?

Comment: @Fox it's logic implemented in the blocking collection in terms of Windows threading primitives. I'd surmise (without checking the source) that it tells Windows to wait on a kernel event (not the same thing as a .NET event) that gets triggered by the add routine.

Comment: @BACON Okay, but why does it wait in the first place? Normally when you use foreach on something empty it just does nothing. Does the usage of the ConsumingEnumerator change that here?

Comment: @Craig Does it work with linux then? Using .net-core here

Comment: Again, think of data that is consumed faster than it's produced.  As the consumer(s) "catch up" to the producer the collection may become empty. Just because there is no more data to process _now_ doesn't mean there won't be in the _future_, so the enumerator(s) need to be kept "alive" for if and when that happens.  `GetConsumingEnumerator()` enables this `foreach` usage by, among other things, only terminating enumeration once `BlockingCollection<>.IsCompleted` is `true` (meaning `Count` is `0` _and_ `CompleteAdding()` has been called). Remember it supports multiple producers or consumers.

Comment: @Fox for Linux, I'm not sure what primitives it would use, but I would expect it to use an approximate equivalent of the Windows primitives.

Comment: Re what happens with `For Each`, what's happening behind the scenes is a call to the enumerator's `MoveNext` method (to advance and check if the end is reached) and a read of the `Current` property.  In the case of the `ConsumingIterator`, I would expect that `MoveNext` simply blocks until it has something (or nothing) to return.

Comment: @Craig I didn‘t even know that foreach works that way, I see now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses `SemaphoreSlim` to wait on `GetConsumingEnumerable` and `Release` is called when items are added (highly simplified).

> SemaphoreSlim is a lightweight alternative to the `Semaphore` class that
> doesn't use Windows kernel semaphores.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1

You can read the whole code for [BlockingCollection](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the source! Together with the info from @Craig on how foreach actually works I've understood it now.